# removeClass - doesn't work

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I like Remove sel-scroll

```
<ul class="selection-list sel-scroll sel-items js-items-unchecked" id="yui_3_11_1_1377278254438_3699">
```

But dont work `$('.sel-scroll').removeClass('sel-scroll');`

any ideas?  by the way I am beginner in jquery, try to explain it clearly.

This data is contained in a checkbox, type facebook.

Comment: You should update your original question instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 2):

how does it not work? here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BFEFU/) where it works fine.

```
$('.sel-scroll').removeClass('sel-scroll');
```

Comment: what are you asking? your code removes the class 'sel-scroll' from elements that have that class. Are you trying to do something else?

Comment: the problem is that I run the javascript code but does not eliminate, only removed if entered inspect item and delete it manually

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. If you view the jsfiddle, the class is clearly removed.

Comment: in jsFiddle if it works, but on the website, do not delete anything, does not affect anything, we will have to set some id? or something? to understand the code that has to affect that particular site.

Comment: the only way we would possibly be able to tell is by looking at your site, or looking at the complete code.

Comment: an email to resend? is that the code has private data

Comment: the jQuery code has private data in it? we certainly don't need to see any private data. If you can provide the complete jQuery code with any private data obfuscated, we might be able to identify the problem.

Comment: download this is the code html http://www.mediafire.com/view/voyz3lp8eiut7c1/html_ok.txt

Comment: this is some of the worst, nightmarish code I have ever seen. If Lovecraft wrote code, this is what he would write. There is no way I can take the time to try to sort out this mess. Sorry.

Comment: if you mount the code in a browser, it seems less chaotic jajaja

Comment: no, it's still chaotic.

Comment: hehe ok, because I will continue looking to see if I with the key